# Заполнение таблицы БД: если элемента нет, то нужно его добавить

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Я проверяю таблицу на существования в ней элемента, если его нет, то нужно его добавить. Добавляем, происходит ошибка (ID уникальный) — он проверяет строки и если нету элемента, то он добавляет. Как сделать так, чтобы он за раз проверил все элементы и добавил 1 раз, а не по кол-ву строк? Так как он проверяет каждую строку и пытается добавлять.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('diploma.db')
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT chat_id from users")
for row in cursor:
    if not in row:
       conn = sqlite3.connect('diploma.db')
       conn.execute("INSERT INTO users (chat_id, USERNAME) \
                                                        VALUES (8,'KOS')")
       conn.commit()
```

Comment: Приведите куски кода (отредактировав ваш вопрос), которые выполняют описанные вами операции, иначе совершенно ничего непонятно.

Comment: Любой текст лучше вставлять в вопрос как текст - картинки имеют свойство удаляться с хостингов, плохо отображаться на мобилах, нельзя выделить текст и скопировать себе, также поиск по картинкам не работает и люди с похожей проблемой не смогут найти вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо комбинации `SELECT` и затем `INSERT`, используйте `INSERT OR IGNORE`. Записи, не имеющие аналогов (по любому уникальному индексу, в т.ч. и первичному) будут добавлены, а записи-дубликаты - проигнорированы.

Comment: Ругается,пишет DB is locked.